# Angularjs ui-router with accumulative states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to make an interface where every state, after exit that state its view remains on the DOM, what I'm experimenting with the code below is logically correct, every time I transition to another state, the view of the previuos state is removed from the DOM.

```
    (function() {

      this.plotter = angular.module('plotter', ['ui.state']);

      this.plotter.config([
        '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
          return $stateProvider.state('plotter', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<div ui-view="scoresview"></div><div ui-view="plotsview"></div>',
            controller: function() {
              return console.log("main");
            }
          }).state('plotter.scores', {
            views: {
              'scoresview': {
                template: '<div>scores!</div>',
                controller: function() {
                  return console.log("scores!");
                }
              }
            },
            onEnter: function() {},
            onExit: function() {}
          }).state('plotter.plots', {
            views: {
              'plotsview': {
                template: '<div>plos!</div>',
                controller: function() {
                  return console.log("plots!");
                }
              }
            },
            onEnter: function() {},
            onExit: function() {}
          });
        }
      ]).run(['$state', function ($state) {          
          $state.transitionTo('plotter');
      }]);

    }).call(this);
```

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p1nox/jY3L5) example on the ui-router docs where they are making something related but different I think. If you watch my code above, you'll see what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I made it (misunderstanding the concept of multiple views):

```
(function() {

  var score_view = {
    template: '<div>scores!</div>',
    controller: function() {
      return console.log("scores!");
    }
  };

  var plot_view = {
    template: '<div>plos!</div>',
    controller: function() {
      return console.log("plots!");
    }
  };

  this.plotter = angular.module('plotter', ['ui.state']);

  this.plotter.config([
    '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
      return $stateProvider.state('plotter', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<div ui-view="step1"></div><div ui-view="step2"></div>',
        controller: function() {
          return console.log("main");
        }
      }).state('plotter.scores', {
        views: {
          'step1': score_view 
        },
        onEnter: function() {},
        onExit: function() {}
      }).state('plotter.plots', {
        views: {
          'step1': score_view, 
          'step2': plot_view 
        },
        onEnter: function() {},
        onExit: function() {}
      });
    }
  ]).run(['$state', function ($state) {          
      $state.transitionTo('plotter');
  }]);

}).call(this);
```